# Why did the Magic Council make so many Faces?

Tags: fairy-tail

If Face can eradicate all magic on Fiore, why did the council make so many of them?

Magic is their first line of defence, after all, they are the **Magic Council**. But even if something did come up where they needed to eradicate magic, why would they make so many Faces, especially if they were trying to keep them a big secret?

I could understand if there are 2 or 3, but why hundreds?

If they had multiple, it would make more sense to spread them out, but why would they keep them all in the same place?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is because of people like Zeref.

It's the last line of defense. If all else fails, they had enough Faces to make sure the eradication of magic would be complete. Of course, that plan failed too.

That would be my thought process: if magic couldn't stop magic, eradicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Faces are made as military defense weapons to protect the Fiore Kingdom. 
Such weapons can shock foreign intruders so that they dare not start a war. 
This will be detailed explained in later chapters.

Comment: Yeah, but if it only takes one to wipe out all magic why do they need so many?

Comment: Maybe one can wipe out all the magic of a land, but there is not only one land in this world. And now you see Wendy can also break a Face, if there are so many Faces, they will not be broken easily by human.

Comment: But if it only wiped out magic from one land then the magic from other lands would just seep back into the first land.

Comment: @user30104 For devils, if they wipe out magic from on land, they can kill others who obstruct them easily so that they can wake up END and complete their mission. They don't care about whether human can use magic again if they achieve their purpose.

Comment: yeah but the devils aren't the ones who built them they were just going to use them, so why would that have anything to do with why the Magic Council building them

Comment: ......  So I think if there are enough Faces being launched, all the magic in the world could be wiped out. But if there is only one, it cannot make it.